# First Java Data Structures Assignment

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, postfix-notation

edit - I revised my code and replaced my original work with new code, still having similar issues

This data structures class I'm taking is my first programming course, so I'm a bit out of my element. The first project is really kicking my ass. It is to make a Reverse Polish Notation Calculator. It is more or less complete, just a lot of bugs. I have been spending hours tweaking my code but when I address one problem it unleashes another. I apologize in advance for my horrible programming skills.

public class ReversePolishStack {

```
class SinglyLinkList {
    Node head = null;

    public void push(float newData) {
        Node cache = this.head;
        this.head = new Node(newData, cache);
    }

    public float pop() {
        float out = this.head.data;
        head = head.next;
        return out;
    }
    public void add(float num1, float num2) {
            num1 = pop();                       
            num2 = pop();
            push(num1+num2);
        }
    public void sub(float num1, float num2) {
            num1 = pop();                       
            num2 = pop();
            push(num2-num1);
        }
    public void div(float num1, float num2) {
            num1 = pop();                       
            num2 = pop();
            push(num2/num1);
        }
    public void mult(float num1, float num2) {
            num1 = pop();                       
            num2 = pop();
            push(num1*num2);
        }
    class Node {
        public float data;
        public Node next;

        public Node(float data, Node next) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
}     
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReversePolishStack rps = new ReversePolishStack();
    SinglyLinkList sll = rps.new SinglyLinkList(); 
    String entry;
    do
    {
        System.out.print("Enter Expression:\n");       
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        entry =in.nextLine();           
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(entry," ");                        
        String s1;
        int count = 0;
        while (st.hasMoreElements()) 
        {               
            if (entry.length()<4)   {// for an error message not enough input
                System.out.print("Not enough input"); break;
            }
            else if (count>1 && sll.head.next==null) {
                System.out.print("Not enough operands"); break;
            }                             
            s1 = st.nextToken();          
            if((s1.equals("+") || s1.equals("-") || s1.equals("*") || s1.equals("/")))  {                             
                if(s1.equals("+"))
                    sll.add(sll.head.data, sll.head.next.data);
                else if(s1.equals("-"))
                    sll.sub(sll.head.data, sll.head.next.data);
                else if(s1.equals("/")) {
                    if (sll.head.data==0)   {
                        System.out.println("Division by Zero enounterd."); break;
                    }
                    sll.div(sll.head.data, sll.head.next.data);
                }
                else if(s1.equals("*"))
                    sll.mult(sll.head.data, sll.head.next.data);
                else
                    System.out.print("Unrecognized input");break;
            }
            else {
                sll.push(Float.parseFloat(s1));
            }
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println(sll.head.data);
        sll.pop();
    } while(entry.equals("0")== false); // typeing a single zero terminates
    System.out.print("Thanks for using my RPN Calculator!");
}
```

}

I have been at this for awhile and I'm sure with every attempt at fixing a bug I also added to the convolution that is my code. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: lets go one by one.. whats ur current problem :-)

Comment: That won't even compile! classes declared inside main method?? Is that a c&p error?

Comment: I'm surprised there weren't prerequisutes for this course

Comment: [G V] Mainly I wanted people to point out the big issues like if I'm going about something wrong, and like the next commented mentioned class inside main method.
[Fildor] Thanks for the help.
[peeskiller] There are pre-requisites... SHHHHHHHHHHHH, but I've been doing fine until now. I have a 86% in the class about 1/3 way through. One of my ex-military professors once said, "If you ain't cheating, you ain't trying." If furthering my education is wrong, than I don't want to be right. I do admit it is unfair to the people trying to get into the class that has done the prereqs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should take out from the main method the classes you have defined.
After that you'll get an error because an instance of the class `singlyLinkList` (`singlyLinkList sll = new singlyLinkList();`) has been created without creating the outer class (`ReversePolishStack`).

See as reference [this link about nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

I also put the `Node` class into the `singlyLinkList` class (btw you should rename this class as `SinglyLinkList` with the first letter capitalized).

I didn't get into the logic of your code but at least after these fixes your code will compile:

```
public class ReversePolishStack {

    class singlyLinkList {
        Node head = null;

        public void push(float newData) {
            Node cache = this.head;
            this.head = new Node(newData, cache);
        }

        public float pop() {
            float out = this.head.data;
            head = head.next;
            return out;
        }

        class Node {
            public float data;
            public Node next;

            public Node(float data, Node next) {
                this.data = data;
                this.next = next;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float number1;
        float number2;
        ReversePolishStack rps = new ReversePolishStack();
        singlyLinkList sll = rps.new singlyLinkList();
        System.out.print("Enter Expression:\n");
                // from here will be the same as you wrote
        }
}
```

I also suggest you to extract the logic of your program from your main method and create methods in the `ReversePolishStack` in order to use the oop concepts.

Hope this was useful!
Ciao!